# Replicate SAS GLM proc to R

Tags: r, sas, glm

I want to compute a linear model in order to get means of some `Y` variable adjusted on a categorial `Q` variable and some `X` numeric variables.

One told me I could easily get them with SAS, and I used this piece of code:

```
proc glm data=TABLE_R;
    class Q(ref="Q1");
    model Y = Q X2 X3 X4 / solution;
    lsmeans Q/ stderr pdiff cov out=adjmeans;
run;
```

But being way more friendly with R, I wanted to replicate this procedure, and after some research I ended with this code:

```
m = glm(Y ~ Q + X2 + X3 + X4, data=db) #using lm() didn't change anything
emmeans::emmeans(m, "Q")
```

The problem is that, whether very close, model coefficients are different. Here is an example with the `intercept` and 2 levels of `Q`:

```
#in R
  (Intercept)                  Q2                  Q3         
-0.1790444126        0.0051160461       -0.0013756817
#in SAS
  (Intercept)                  Q2                  Q3         
-0.1767853086        0.0016709301       -0.0031477746
```

Actually, in SAS, I have a message saying that coefficients needed additional computation (which I unfortunately don't understand, does R `glm()` lack this ?):

> Note: The X'X matrix has been found to be singular, and a generalized
>   inverse was used to solve the normal equations.  Terms whose estimates
>   are followed by the letter 'B' are not uniquely estimable.

**Which option should I add here or ther so I can find the same results with both SAS and R ?**

**If I cannot, how can I choose which method is best suited ?**

*Usefull posts : [Proc GLM (SAS) using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083586/proc-glm-sas-using-r), [X'X matrix found to be singular](http://support.sas.com/kb/22/585.html)*

EDIT : This is very strange but effectives are different in SAS and R :

```
#SAS
Observations read: 81733
Observations used: 9000
#R
16357 Residual
(88017 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Comment: Does SAS use the same treatment contrasts as R does?

Comment: The SAS message just states that the matrix X'X (the product of the regressor matrix and its transpose, which is used in estimating the coefficients) is not uniquely invertible and therefore a generalized inverse is used. This in itself should not be a problem, but it could explain the small differences if SAS and R use different methods to calculate the pseudoinverse.

Comment: @Roland How could I know ?

Comment: @LAP is there any way to do the same with R ? this way I'd really know what am I doing :-)  (so I can work to understand it then)

Comment: I just took a quick look at `glm()` and `glm.fit()`, but the functions are pretty obscure. You'd have to dig into the source code to find the bit that calculates the X'X matrix.

Comment: By studying the documentation? You must know this if you are doing regression with categorical variables. Otherwise, you cannot interpret the result.

Comment: @LAP: I doubt that R actually inverts this matrix.

Comment: @Roland Yeah, I just looked into the github repository and the fitting is done by some FORTRAN script.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the same coefficients if you first do

```
options(contrasts=c(“contr.SAS”,”contr.poly”))
```

before fitting the model. This will cause R to use the same parameterization that SAS uses.

However, even without this change, the fitted values from R will be identical to those from SAS, and the EMMs from R will match the lsmeans from SAS. That’s because we are not really changing the model, we are only changing how it is parameterized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your last sentence. My example is quite clear about values being different. Anyway, I'm sorry but your code changed parameters in R but they don't match those from SAS. Actually SAS always put 0 as the coefficient for the reference level of a class, whereas R doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: R just skips the reference level. That is the same as setting its coefficient to 0. I.e., b1x1 + b2x2 + 0x3 = b1 x1 + b2x2.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my last sentence was stupid. But still the rest of my comment is correct, coefficients don't match in SAS and R.

Comment: Then I think the data must be different. Maybe you omitted a case or something?

Comment: I exported my data in csv with R and import it with SAS-EG, so I really doubt it. Besides, I just checked my effective and there indeed is something fishy (please see my edit)